# Alt Gr key gives menu focus when I don't expect it to

Tags: javafx, focus, textfield, menubar

Several keyboards have a [Alt Gr key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key). On my Swedish keyboard layout, to enter the `[` character I have to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>).

If I were to input this character *twice* in a JavaFX `TextField`, where the application also has a `MenuBar`, the menu bar keeps the focus instead of the text field. This makes me have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> again to make the `TextField` get focus. I'd want the `TextField` to have focus after I enter any character with the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key.

**Code to reproduce problem:**

```
public class MenuTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane pane = new VBox();

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.getMenus().add(new Menu("_File"));
        menuBar.getMenus().add(new Menu("_Test"));

        TextField input = new TextField();

        pane.getChildren().add(menuBar);
        pane.getChildren().add(input);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

With the `TextField` having focus do:

- With your keyboard layout set to Swedish, press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>) twice. For other keyboard layouts, enter any character of your choice that includes the usage of the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key.
- Press left arrow

**Expected behavior:** Two `[` characters are inserted into the `TextField`. Caret is moved one step to the left in the `TextField`.

**Actual behavior:** Two `[` characters are inserted into the `TextField`. Another menu is highlighted and has focus

**Question:**

Why is this happening? Even Windows' basic Notepad application behaves according to my expectations here.

Is there any way I can make the actual behavior match the expected behavior?

Comment: I you are using Ubuntu it could be related to this bug in Unity: https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-core/+bug/1233458

Comment: @FrederikH Unfortunately I am using Windows, but I could try to see what happens with different OS. Thanks for the link though.